# Spark on Amazon Spot Market

Tags: apache-spark

I can see that a use-case for Apache Spark is running it on the Amazon Spot market, as the spark-ec2 script has a `--spot-price=<price>` option.

How would spark it handle new instances coming online or suddenly disappearing?  Wold my jobs be automatically rescheduled?  Where is this discussed in the docs?

**Update**
A bit more digging revealed that the fault tolerance of RDDs is taken care of by recalculating as necessary.  For my problem this isn't optimal, since the computation is very expensive (and stochastic).  Looking into Akka now to roll my own bespoke alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in the Spark documentation (afaik), however your best bet is to look at [the Amazon documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-interruptions.html) as it is going to be the same for any distributed computation.

As far as spark itself, it is built to be fault tolerant. So, if a running node is killed, then it will attempt to re-create the data from the most recent graph.